# XSS attack with javascript in img src attribute

Tags: xss, security

Some older browsers are vulnerable to XSS attacks as such

```
<img src="javascript:alert('yo')" />
```

Current versions of IE, FF, Chrome are not.

I am curious if any browsers are vulnerable to a similar attack:

```
<img src="somefile.js" />
```

or

```
<iframe src="somefile.js" />
```

or other similar where somefile.js contains some malicious script.

Comment: How about "try and see for yourself"?

Comment: I did with modern versions of IE, FF and Chrome.  Don't have any older browsers so that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Image data is never executed as JavaScript. The if the src is a JavaScript link, the JavaScript is executed, but the fundamental reading of data that comes from a request to the src does not involve JavaScript.

Comment: What about the iframe? Does the above apply to it as well?

Comment: No, JavaScript is not executed then either.

Comment: Not quite true. There are some XSS attacks that can run JS inside image src

Answer (score 55):

All major browsers are still vulnerable to these attacks.
Tons of ways of using img tags are still around.. 
For example...

`<img src='#' onerror=alert(1) />`

Look for RSnake's xss cheatsheet, those are just some vectors. By the way, I've heard he's coming up with a new version of his cheatsheet soon.

Comment: Nice trick but if there is an XSS vulnerability and the website is correctly using CSP headers, it will not work.
I tried this code in the browser console on https://securityheaders.com/:
`var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", "#");
img.setAttribute("onerror", "alert(1);");
document.body.appendChild(img);`
Error message: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: onerror attribute on IMG element.`

Answer (score 2):

here you can find some XSS attacking vector
http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: fresh link [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)