# Scope of Javascript inside src attribute of image

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I have to do an XSS-Attack for a security related university project. I want to store an image that has malicious code inside its source attribute. However, it seems to be that I don't have access to any javascript objects from the the src attribute.

Here are some things I tried:

```
<img src="j&#X41vascript:alert('XSS')">
```

Throws: Reference Error alert is not defined.

```
<img src="j&#X41vascript:window.alert('XSS')">
```

Throws: Reference Error window is not defined

```
<img src="j&#X41vascript:var x = new XMLHttpRequest();">
```

Throws: Reference Error XMLHttpRequest is not defined

What is the problem here, and how can I access the main window of the site and the objects I want to access?

**EDIT:**
Onerror and all the other events are filtered.

Comment: This comment is not really helpfull. why is it not executed? And the error  implies that it is executed.

Comment: Can you do something like `javascript:'http//yourserver.example?js='+Object` (and look what is arriving at yourserver)?

Comment: Not all browsers are vulnerable to this attack. What browser are you targeting/testing -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798633/xss-attack-with-javascript-in-img-src-attribute

Comment: I'm testing on Firefox.

Comment: There is no way to execute Javascript codes through src attribute of img. ( I assume that quotes are encoded ) . Also have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798633/xss-attack-with-javascript-in-img-src-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` isn't executed, so that won't work.

A solution would be to use `onerror` :

```
<img src="wrong" onerror="alert('XSS')">
```

Depending on how your `src` attribute is injected, you may be able to pass this value :

```
wrong" onerror="alert('XSS')
```

But no decent framework is vulnerable to that kind of attack.

Comment: Actually, the `javascript` pseudo protocol denotes anything following is interpreted as JavaScript.

Comment: @Gumbo On the src attribute with a not super old browser ? I don't think so.